# Show div on link click is not working properly

Tags: jquery, css

I want to show a `div` `.items` when the link with id `addItems` is clicked, but it's not working properly. When the `addItems` link is clicked, the `div` `.items` appears, the page refreshes and scrolls to the top and the `.items` `div` hides automatically. Do you know what the issue is?

```js
$('#addItems').click(function() {
  $('.items').show("slide");
});
```

```css
.items {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" class="clearfix">
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="" id="addItems">Add Item</a>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <h6>Items</h6>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName"> Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3" value="Store" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried removing the `href=""` from you `<a>`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bet4ob8o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *default behaviour* of the anchor link needs to be *prevented* from occurring naturally.

Consider the following jQuery method: `event.preventDefault()`

> **Description:** If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.
>
> For example, clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL.

Ref: [event.preventDefault() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
$('#addItems').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.items').show("slide");
  console.log('no refresh');
});
```

```css
.items {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" class="clearfix">
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="" id="addItems">Add Item</a>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <h6>Items</h6>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName"> Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3" value="Store" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The hyperlink elements follow their `href` attribute by default. You set it to nothing, which reloads the same page. To disable this behavior, you can set it to `href="#"`.

```js
$('#addItems').click(function() {
  $('.items').show("slide");
});
```

```css
.items {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" class="clearfix">
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="#" id="addItems">Add Item</a>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <h6>Items</h6>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName"> Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3" value="Store" />
  </div>
</form>
```

**EDIT** To completely disable the `href` so the page doesn't scroll to the top, you can use `href="javascript: void 0;"`:

```js
$('#addItems').click(function() {
  $('.items').show("slide");
});
```

```css
.items {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" class="clearfix">
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="javascript: void 0;" id="addItems">Add Item</a>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <h6>Items</h6>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName"> Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3" value="Store" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. But like that the div appears and its not hidden but the page scrolls to the top, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: OK, so you need to completely disable the link, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `href=""` from the `<a>` element, and the best practice is using the `role="button"` attribute to tell the search engine that this is a button.

Totally, the code will be:

```
 <form method="post" class="clearfix">
    <div class="form-group">
        <a role="button" id="addItems">Add Item</a>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
        <h6>Items</h6>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputName"> Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3" value="Store"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the browser is trying to follow the href attribute of your `<a>` tag.  Some things you could try:

1. Replace `<a>` with a `<span>` tag and style it to look like an anchor tag
2. Add `e.preventDefault` in your function to stop the page from attempting to reload. Would look like this:

   `$('#addItems').click(function(e){
       $('.items').show("slide");
       e.preventDefault();
   });`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `href` which by default redirects the user to another page. Remove it or change it by for example a `<button>`

Now it works

```js
$('#addItems').click(function() {
        $('.items').show("slide");
});
```

```css
.items{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" class="clearfix">
    <div class="form-group">
        <a id="addItems"><u>Add Item</u></a>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
        <h6>Items</h6>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputName"> Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3" value="Store"/>
        </div>
</form>
```